# Gerrit configuration; Unable to create new object

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

In the documentation of the Jenkins "Gerrit Trigger" plugin is written that is needed the following configuration in Gerrit:

> Gerrit web interface > People > Create New Group : "Event Streaming
>   Users". Add your jenkins user.
>
> Admin > Projects > All-Projects > Access > Edit Global Capabilities
>   Stream Events: ALLOW for Event Streaming Users

When trying to save the changes, e.g. adding "ALLOW for Event Streaming Users" I get an error from the Gerrit server:

```
Code Review - Error

Server Error

Unable to create new object: /home/gerrit2/gerrit-github-installation/git/All-Projects.git/objects/4c/3f6c52b57811228a96b41469517040487bb7b
```

It seems to be some access right at the server that are wrong but I can not figure out where I need to update. Note: I'm a Gerrit "administrator".

Comment: Check which user executes the GerritCodeReview process (ps -elf | grep GerritCodeReview) and if this user has permission to create files in /home/gerrit2/gerrit-github-installation/git/All-Projects.git/objects.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. The "gerrit2" user has access to the "objects" directory but the "4c" directory  is owned by "root"  and "gerrit2" does not have write permissions to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: check if you are a Gerrit administrator, only administrators can change the access permissions of the All-Projects project. If you are not an administrator, ask to someone to do this for you.

Then: check which user executes the GerritCodeReview process (ps -elf | grep GerritCodeReview) and if this user has permission to create files in /home/gerrit2/gerrit-github-installation/git/All-Projects.gi‌​t/objects. If something is wrong, adjust the filesystem permission accordingly (chown or/and chmod commands).

Comment: I am administrator